# How to access the first column in SQL and why does this code give me error?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Can someone tell my why my `expectedNumber` reader throws an error

> The name reader does not exist in its current context

As far as I can see all this is doing is reading the first row and first column, don't understand why the reader is throwing a tantrum.

It doesn't like the line:

```
ExpectedNumber = reader.GetInt16(0);
```

The query is :

```
SELECT TOP (1) [ExpectedNumber] 
FROM [dbo].[MyDatabase] 
WHERE id = '{0}'
```

Code:

```
try
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format(Query, id), Connection))
    {
        Connection.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Check is the reader has any rows at all before starting to read.
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                int ExpectedNumber = 0;
                // Read advances to the next row.
                while (reader.Read() == true)
                {
                    // To avoid unexpected bugs access columns by name.
                    ExpectedNumber = reader.GetInt16(0);
                }

                Connection.Close();

                return ExpectedResult;
            }

            Assert.Fail("No results returned from expected result query");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Connection.Close();
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Could you include the query as well?

Comment: Do you mean you are getting the compile time error `CS0103 The name 'reader' does not exist in the current context` ? That does not make sense with the above code. However I would expect the above code to give the compile time error `CS0103 The name 'ExpectedResult' does not exist in the current context` because you are returning ExpectedResult when it would look like you mean ExpectedNumber.

Comment: If `Id` is the primary key, why do you need `TOP (1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape your query parameters, otherwise your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, also, by using command parameters as in the example below you can make sure you are using the right data type (it seems you are trying to pass an int id as a string).

You are just trying to get one value so you don't need to use a reader and can use `ExecuteScalar` instead.

Finally, you don't need to handle closing the connection if you enclose it in a using block so you can avoid the try catch block as well.

```
string query = "SELECT TOP (1) [ExpectedNumber] FROM [dbo].[MyDatabase] WHERE id = @id";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection("connStr")) 
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;

        object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (result != null && result.GetType() != typeof(DBNull))
        {
            return (int)result;
        }
        
        Assert.Fail("No Results Returned from Expected Result Query");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Note: this code assumes you are using SQL Server, for other systems the format of the parameters in the connection string might change, e.g. for Oracle it should be `:id` instead of `@id`.

Comment: don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: I don't see any issue with using AddWithValue on a select statement with an INT parameter but I changed it anyway.